# NextAuth.js callbackUrl and first attempt after sign in

Tags: url, redirect, next.js, callback, next-auth

I am implementing NextAuth authentication and there is something that remains unclear for me. I explain.
To perform authentication with CredentialsProviders and signIn() well (means avoid the session's status **unauthenticated** during the first attempt). The doc gives a partial solution which is:
**You can use useSession() in a way that makes sure you always have a valid session**
I use the default behavior to satisfy this advice by implementing my signIn() method like this

```
  const login_user = async () => {
    const response = await signIn("Credentials", {
      redirect: false,
      username: username,
      password: password,
    });
    if (response?.error) {
      setError(response.error);
    } else {
      setError(null);
    }

    //If user signed successfully we redirect to the dashboard page
    if (response.url && response.ok === true) {
      router.push("/dashboard/general");
    }
  };
```

and it works well.
Now always in the doc, they say that we may add **callbackUrl** to signIn()  **which is the url where you want to redirect the user after successful sign in**.
I configure my redirect callback in [...nextauth].ts file like this

```
  redirect: async ({ url, baseUrl }) => {
      return url.startsWith(baseUrl)
        ? Promise.resolve(url)
        : Promise.resolve(baseUrl);
    },
```

and modify signIn() method by adding it callbackUrl like below in the react component.

```
  const login_user = async () => {
    const response = await signIn("Credentials", {
      redirect: false,
      username: username,
      password: password,
      callbackUrl: "/dashboard/general",
    });
    if (response?.error) {
      setError(response.error);
    } else {
      setError(null);
    }  
  };
```

But when a user sign in, he is not redirected.
My question is:
**What is the role of callbackUrl at that place if after the sign in or first attempt of sign in it cannot redirect the user to the specified callbackUrl?**
I know the importance of callbackUrl about security against attacker)
May be I do not understand well that notion.
Can someone explains it?

Comment: You have `redirect: false` set in the `signIn` call. This prevents the redirection from happening automatically and expects you to handle it manually (like in your first example). Simply removing it or setting it to true should solve the problem. See https://next-auth.js.org/v3/getting-started/client#using-the-redirect-false-option.

Answer (score 1):

Removing redirect helps me to fix.. redirect:false stops the callbackurl when tried to navigate to the page

Comment: Please did you find the way to stop redirecting?